# Unable to add default root no such device error in linux

Tags: linux, gateway, system-administration

I try have access internet so i should add default route to my linux server my ip address is 10.1.1.1 but my default gateway is 20.1.1.1

I tried to add default gateway with `route add default 20.1.1.1` but get 
error :

> siocaddrt: no such device

I tried to use virtual nic like `eth0:0` to add ip address in range my default gateway where linux permit me to add default gateway but again I get error as same last error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution 
first i add route to another subnet

`route add e.f.g.h/32 dev eth0:1`

second i add:

`route add default gw e.f.g.h`

and my problem solved, i hope no one stick in this error .

Answer (score 1):

I think, due to some issue of some bug, you have to:

1-list your routes, ~$ip route

2-Add the route you want~$route add default ...

3-Check that you have your route, gateway, etc. set

4-Reboot

5-ip route delete

6-Do again the step 2-

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple in your case...

The default gateway has to be on the same subnet as the IP address of your network card.

your card's ip must be 20. * . * . *  if you use /8 mask

Comment: i know what is default gateway and my scenario is my server ip is public and gateway has private ip for security i want set another range ip default gateway and i know it's possible i done before for now i can not remember my solution any way thanks !